# VS Cordova Apache Error

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I built a simple Phone Application with Tools Apache for Cordova. The application works fine when i test it with Ripple - Nexus S for example. But now i tried to test the application on a Samsung Galaxy S2. I plugged in the device and tried to build with the Device configuration in Debug mode. But I got the following error:

```
Error   2   cmd: Command failed with exit code 2    D:\Cordova\Apps\TestApp PhoneGap\TestApp PhoneGap\MDAVSCLI  1   1   TestApp PhoneGap


1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp PhoneGap, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  D:\Cordova\Apps\TestApp PhoneGap\TestApp PhoneGap>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\SCUXRJW3.ZUV\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried to configure the phone with USB Debugging enabled, then tried with USB mass storage and still the same. I also tried to clear Cordova Cache from Tools->Option->Tools for Apache Cordova and I still get the same error. Here is a picture with how i try to run if I wasn't clear: http://postimg.org/image/68crk94az/

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved..
The problem was not the name. Before installing Cordova for Visual Studio, I installed some components and manually added the paths. I deleted everything and then i installed Cordova again, and it was ok

Answer (score 0):

your solution name and project name "TestApp PhoneGap" contains a SPACE, try to build a new solution and new project as "TestAppPhoneGap" without the SPACE.

In my case, I got similar problem and after remove the space, the build is succeeded!